# dynamics crm plugin retrieve related entity attributes value

Tags: plugins, crm, microsoft-dynamics

i'm writing plugin to send sms to multiple users, the scenario is :

-i have a custom entity smsmessmage who has 1-N relationship with users entity
when creating sms message, i need my plugin to extract from users entity a mobile phone for each user selected to send him sms.

any code sample will be helpful.
thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use following code:

```
Entity user = service.Retrieve("systemuser", userid, new ColumnSet("mobilephone"));
string mobilephone = user.GetAttributeValue<string>("mobilephone");
```

Where service is an instance of IOrganizationService you ca get in plugin and userid id identifier of a user to whom you need to send sms.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var query = new QueryExpression("contact") {ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true)};
                        query.Criteria.AddCondition("contactid", ConditionOperator.Equal, new Guid("user_id"));
                        var retrieveMultiple = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
                        if (retrieveMultiple != null && retrieveMultiple.Entities != null && retrieveMultiple.Entities.Any())
                        {
```

//Do here

```
                        }
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.